# In Mongo, how do I unset a field in a map inside an array?

Tags: mongodb

One of my documents looks like this:

```
{:a [{:b "something", :c "else"}, {:b "more" :c "fun"}]}
```

I want to unset the :b element from every map in the array, but the $ operator does not seem to work in this case. What is the way in which this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've hit an "array of objects" issue. When you have an array of objects, MongoDB does not have a full set of `update` operations.

Here's something you *can* do. You have access to `a.0.b` and `a.1.b`. These will access the first and second elements in the array. So you could do something like:

`db.coll.update({_id:"yourid"}, {$unset: {'a.0.b':1,'a.1.b':1}})`

However, you will need to generate the correct query for each document. Some documents may have 2 elements in the array, some may have 10. So there is definitely extra programming required here.

Comment: yes, this is precisely my problem. I was hoping that there would be an elegant solution to it, and that I just didn't know enough about mongo. :(

Comment: Thanks @vedang, this is definitely a region where MongoDB lacks functionality. It supports having arrays of objects, but most of the update operators don't work very well with arrays of objects.